# Convergence in distribution from PGF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$ with positive integer values  and let $G_n(z)$ be the probability generating function of $X_n$, i.e.

$$ G_n(z)=\mathbb{E}[z^{X_n}]=\sum_{k\geq 0}\mathbb{P}(X_n=k)z^k $$

I would like to know whether there are some explicit conditions on $G_n(z)$ (e.g. growth, derivatives,...) for which one would have

$$ \frac{X_n-\mathbb{E}[X_n]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[X_n]}} \to \mathcal{N}(0,1) $$

in distribution.

My question arises from the following situation: consider for each $n$ the random variable $X_n$ that takes the values $2,\dots,n$ with probability
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_n=k)=\frac{\binom{n}{k}(k-1)}{K_n} \quad \text{where} \quad K_n=\sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k}(k-1) = (n-2)2^{n-1}+1  $$
Then the PGFs are given by
$$ G_n(z)=\frac{1}{K_n}[nz(1+z)^{n-1}-(1+z)^n+1] $$
and I have proven that there is the above convergence in distribution in these steps:

- I computed the mean and the variance of the $X_n$ using the formulas
  $$ \mathbb{E}[X_n]=G'_n(1) \qquad \mathbb{E}[X_n^2]=G''_n(1)+G'_n(t) $$
- I have computed the moment generating functions of the $X_n$ with the formula
  $$ \psi_{X_n}(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=G_n(e^t) $$
- I have shown that the moment generating functions of the normalized variables converge to the moment generating function of the standard gaussian:
  $$ \psi_{\frac{X_n-\mathbb{E}[X_n]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[X_n]}}}(t)=e^{-\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_n]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[X_n]}}t}\psi_{X_n}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[X_n]}}\right) \to e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$$

Thus, I was wondering whether I could have skipped the intermediate steps and prove the convergence in distribution directly from the PGF.

Comment: I believe so. convergence in MFG (or Characteristic function) is equivalent to convergence in distribution.

Comment: Yes, I know of this and actually I used this for my proof above. My question was whether I could have skipped the three bullet point steps by studying directly the PGF. I am sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: ah i see! sorry! MFG and PGF are equivalent, but I don't know if you do a convergence proof with PGF.

Comment: No problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The PGF determine uniquely the characteristic functions $\varphi_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, $t\mapsto E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itX_n})$, and the pointwise convergence of the characteristic functions to a characteristic function is equivalent to the convergence in distribution (this is called Lévy theorem). Thus, you are done if the last convergence in your post occurs when $t$ is pure imaginary (it does).

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I have not been clear in my question. I know that convergence of MGF implies convergence in distribution, but I would like to know whether I could have discovered the convergence without computing the MGF (or the characteristic function), but directly from the PGF.

Comment: The characteristic function is the PGF evaluated on $\mathrm i\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, but what I had in mind was some conditions on the coefficients, or something else that would have allowed me to determine the convergence without plugging $e^{it}$ in the PGF.